# How can I unit test the modification of an XML file which recursively points to other XML files?

Tags: xml, unit-testing

I am attempting to unit test the modification of an XML structure like:

```
<element1>
    <open file="otherfile.xml">
</element1>
```

Suppose that `otherfile.xml` contains:

```
<element2>
    <open file="anotherfile.xml">
    <happytag/>
</element2>
```

And that `anotherfile.xml` looks like:

```
<element3>
    <sadtag/>
</element3>
```

The correct modification copies and pastes code from the file to be opened into the code that called the `open` tag.  Therefore, I am expecting a structure like:

```
<element1>
    <element2>
        <element3>
            <sadtag/>
        </element3>
        <happytag/>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

The problem I am having is that I am unsure how to go about unit testing the creation of this structure.  Ideally, and what I have tried to far (unsuccessfully), is to create this unit test so that I do not need to make any calls to the file system in order to create the structure.  To do that, I create a mock object which pretends to be an input stream which opens a file, but is really just returning a stream created from the text of

```
<element1>
    <open file="otherfile.xml">
</element1>
```

The problem I have in this approach is that I cannot figure out a way to inject the text of `otherfile.xml` so that a mock object will return the text of:

```
<element2>
    <open file="anotherfile.xml">
    <happytag/>
</element2>
```

Another thing I've tried is to put the text of `anotherfile.xml` into `open file=""`, like `open file="&lt;element3&gt;...&lt;/element3&gt;">`.  This doesn't work because the XML parser complains that it isn't valid XML.

I could also create these xml files from strings before I run the test and then delete them after the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file accessor interface and then providing two implementations.  One implementation actually opens items on the filesystem.  The other implementation accesses data stored in a map inside the object.

So your testing object would be constructed like this:

```
file_data = {
    "otherfile.xml": "<element2>\n    <open file=\"anotherfile.xml\">\n    <happytag/>\n</element2>",
    "anotherfile.xml": "<element3>\n    <sadtag/>\n</element3>"
}
accessor = TestFileAccessor(file_data)
```